# Copy data from powerpoint textbox to Excel cell

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I am using macro in MS Excel to import data from textbox in PowerPoint to Excel.

It's importing data in text format not able to copy new line characters from textbox

```
Range("a1").Value = pps.Shapes("textbox 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
```

Can anyone please suggest alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of PowerPoint use Chr$(11) as a linebreak character.  It looks like Excel wants a linefeed Chr$(10), so something like this:

```
Range("a1").Value = Replace(pps.Shapes("textbox 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text,Chr$(11), Chr$(10))
```

PPT uses different characters for paragraph endings vs line breaks, and it varies somewhat between versions, so if you need to support PPT 2003 and prior, you'll need a bit more code.

This page on the PPT FAQ I maintain explains the details:

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00992_Paragraph_endings_and_line_breaks.htm

Comment: make another replace after the one that @Steve Rindsberg done
Replace(text, Chr$(13), Chr$(10))