# Copy textbox from PowerPoint to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, powerpoint

There is a similar question. It has an answer but did not work for me. I've used some of their code and hoping someone could point out what i might be doing wrong.
[Copy data from powerpoint textbox to Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773668/copy-data-from-powerpoint-textbox-to-excel-cell)

I've got a power point with many slides/textboxes, among other objects. I'd like to copy all the text from the text boxes to an excel spreadsheet. If I could just get the syntax for one i'm pretty sure i could loop through the slide deck.

```
Option Explicit
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application

Sub GetTextboxes()
Set PPT = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

Set pptPres = PPT.Presentations.Open("D:\Documents\Briefs.pptx")
Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides(1)
Range("A1").Value = pptSlide.Shapes("Textbox1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run that?

Comment: O wow... I had the wrong name for the text box. I also have to have powerpoint open for it to work. Thank you for asking me that and having me check. I must have been tired yesterday to overlook that detail.